ngx-color-picker problem with scrolling pages?
i'm getting a problem with ngx-color-picker.
In my project i have a list of element into a standard table using @for.
In each row i have a column with a button where i can change the color of that row, and it works well except for one thing.
If I have a long list of elements such that I have to scroll the page, the picker no longer remains "hooked" to the buttons I click on but starts to open a couple of lines away upwards, here is an example of what I mean.

Has anyone had similar experiences or could help me understand how I can ensure that when I open the picker it remains exactly in a specific position with respect to the button I have opened regardless of the height of the page?
Here is the code.
HTML:
<tbody>
        @for (element of elements(); track element.ID; let i = $index) {
          <tr class="table-element-row" cdkDrag [style.background-color]="element.BackgroundColor">
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(0) }">
              <i
                class="fas fa-palette ms-1"
                style="font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer"
                [(colorPicker)]="element.BackgroundColor"
                [cpPresetColors]="rowColors"
                [cpPresetLabel]="'Presets'"
                (colorPickerClose)="changeColorSelected($event, element)"
                [cpToggle]="false"
                [cpPosition]="'auto'"
                [cpPositionRelativeToArrow]="true"
                (click)="fixPickerPosition($event, element)"
                #colorPicker></i>
            </td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(1) }">
              <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="elementStatusTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ row: element }"></ng-container>
            </td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(2) }">
              {{ element.PMCDenomination?? element.CDenomination }}
            </td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(3) }">{{ element.SbName ?? element.Name }}</td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(4) }">{{ element.SbName }}</td>
            <td>{{ getPMULabel(element) }}</td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(5) }">
              <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="taskCalendarEventTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ row: element }"></ng-container>
            </td>
            <td [style]="{ width: getColumnWidth(6) }">
              <ng-container
                [ngTemplateOutlet]="elementNTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ row: element }"></ng-container>
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      </tbody>

TS:
fixPickerPosition(event: Event, el: any) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const scrollLeft = window.scrollX || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

    const pickerElement = this.colorPicker.nativeElement;

    this.renderer.setStyle(pickerElement, "top", `${rect.top + scrollTop}px`);
    this.renderer.setStyle(pickerElement, "left", `${rect.left + scrollLeft}px`);
  }


please share a stackblitz with the issue happening for checking
